# Number of branch points for a rational map with degree d is 2(d-1)?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, complex-geometry

Let $R(z)=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ where P and Q are complex polynomials. A point in $CP^1$ is said to be a branch point of $R$ if for every neighborhood around $z_0$, R is not a homeomorphism restricted the the neighborhood (in my text we consider rational functions to map into the riemann sphere).  The degree of R is the max of the degree of $P$ and $Q$.  Don't see why the number of branch points for $R$ is $2(d-1)$.  The problem points we should consider are probably where the denominator is zero or when $R$ has a critical point, otherwise we could use inverse functions theorem.  The number of critical points is just the number of zeros of $Q'P+P'Q$ but I don't see how it relates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R=P/Q$ be a rational function of degree $d=\max\{\text{deg } P, \text{deg } Q\}$.

Since $R$ is continuous, your statement is equivalent to:
A point in $CP^1$ is said to be a branch point of $R$ if $R$ fails to be injective on every neighborhood of $z_0$.

Suppose $z_0$ is a branch point of $R$. Then for each neighborhood $B(z_0,n^{-1})= \{z: d(z_0,z)<n^{-1} \}$ ($n=1,2,\ldots$), we may choose two distinct points $z_n, w_n \in B(z_0,n^{-1})$ such that $R(z_n)=R(w_n)$. By the mean value theorem, for each pair of points $z_n, w_n$ ($n=1,2,\ldots$), we may find some point $c_n$ on the straight line from $z_n$ to $w_n$ such that $R'(c_n)=0$. Since $R'$ is continuous and $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n=z_0$, we have that $R'(z_0)=0$.

Now without proof I will note that the degree of
$$R'(z)=\frac{P'(z)Q(z)-P(z)Q'(z)}{\left[Q(z)\right]^2}$$
turns out to be exactly $2(d-1)$.